# CMake get list of tried package when find_package fails

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake project and I want to obtain information when a find_package fails.

My setup is this: I have a project that compiles a few libraries and export the targets. The package is exported to the CMake package registry. Then, I have another project that depends on it.

The thing is, the library project has dependencies too. To make the importing package aware, we are using `find_dependency` in the config file.

When `find_package(libs REQUIRED)` fails because of missing dependencies, I would like to extract the path of the package it tried. I would use that information to maybe update the list of prefix path in order to find the missing dependencies next time, but I only want to do that if the reason of the failed import is missing dependencies.

Is there any way to obtain these information in a failed find package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the CMake documentation for [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html):

> All configuration files which have been considered by CMake while searching for an installation of the package with an appropriate version are stored in the cmake variable `<PackageName>_CONSIDERED_CONFIGS`, the associated versions in `<PackageName>_CONSIDERED_VERSIONS`.

So using `<PackageName>_CONSIDERED_CONFIGS` and `<PackageName>_CONSIDERED_VERSIONS` can tell what packages CMake has found.